# delete node(s) in a singly linked list in c

Tags: c, nodes, singly-linked-list

I created a singly linked list that accepts value from  input. I tried to delete certain nodes from the input but the code isn't executing as intended.

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE {
     int value;
     struct NODE *prev;
};

struct NODE* head = NULL;

void insert(int data) {
   
    struct NODE *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    
   (*p).value = data;
    
   
   (*p).prev = head;
    
   
   head = p;
}

void addBack(struct node **head, int val)
{
    
    struct NODE *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    (*newNode).value = val;
    (*newNode).prev = NULL;

   
    if(*head == NULL)
         *head = newNode;
    else
    {
        struct NODE *headNode = *head;
        while((*headNode).prev != NULL)
        {
            headNode = (*headNode).prev;
        }
        (*headNode).prev = newNode;
    }

}
void printList(struct NODE* head)
{
        while (head != NULL) {
            
        printf("%d",(*head).value);
        
        if((*head).prev!= NULL){
            printf(",");
        }
                head = (*head).prev;
        }
}

void deleteNode(struct NODE** head, int new)
{
    
    struct NODE *tmp = *head, *sa;
    if (tmp != NULL && tmp->value == new) {
        
        free(tmp); 
        return;
    }
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->value != new) {
        sa = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->prev;
    }
    if (tmp == NULL)
        return;
    sa->prev = tmp->prev;
    free(tmp); 
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int array[num];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    
    for(int j = num-1; j >= 0; j--){
    insert(array[j]);
    }
    
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    addBack(&head, x);
    deleteNode(&head, 3);
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

9 is the size of the list, and the random number 3 on the third line is just a new integer that gets added to the list. In this problem, I was trying to remove the value of 3, in which there were 3 of them. The output only removed 1 so I'm wondering what the problem is.

Comment: "*I'm wondering what the problem is*". The way to answer that is to actually debug the code. Run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statement to trace the program execution. Have you done that? What did you find? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471)

Comment: `if (tmp != NULL && tmp->value == new) { free(tmp);` That can't be right because you free the node but don't actually remove it from the list. And why do you treat that as a special case anyway?

Comment: This is typo: `addBack(struct node **head...` It should be `NODE`, not `node`. You should see a compiler warning for this. Don't use this notation `(*p).value`, just use `p->value`. Your node structure contains `prev`, that should be named `next`, because you start at `head` and you move forward.

Comment: Also I suggest removing `scanf` input for the time being. Just declare the array as `int array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };`, then `addBack(&head, 100);` This will make it easier to focus on compiler warnings and debug messages. Put back `scanf` input once complete.

Comment: Whenever the topic of deleting a node from a linked list comes up, it's kind of mandatory to refer to Linus Torvalds' remark, that most implementations lack elegance and are needlessly convoluted. Here's a nice  post explaining this is detail: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273666/the-right-way-to-remove-an-item-from-a-linked-list

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables) (*hint:* your global `head` and parameter `head`). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteNode()` will remove at most the head or the first non-head node with a matching value.  Note, that in the first case you need to update `*head` to the previous node.  You should also handle `head` being `NULL`.

Here is an implementation of `deleteNodes()` that removes all matching nodes.  To avoid the special case of the head node being removed, introduce a `tmp` node so we only have to deal with the non-head case:

```
void deleteNodes(struct NODE **n, int v) {
    if(!n) return;
    struct NODE tmp = {.prev = *n};
    for(struct NODE *p = &tmp; p->prev; ) {
        if(p->prev->value == v) {
            struct NODE *match = p->prev;
            p->prev = p->prev->prev;
            free(match);
        } else {
            p = p->prev;
        }
    }
    *n = tmp.prev;
}
```